# JLabel run function form runnable interface is not being called

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So I read that run function from Runnable interface is automatically called but it is not working for me (run is not being called). This is my first time doing anything in java so I might have done something stupid. The following code is supposed to move a rectangle across the screen. The rectangle is drawn but it is not moving.

Main:

```
    public class Label extends JLabel{

    Game game;

    public Label(Game game){
       this.game = game;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics gfx){
        game.render(gfx);
    }
}
```

Frmae:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    Game game;

    public Frame(Label label, Game game) {
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setTitle("idk");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setEnabled(true);
        this.game = game;
        this.setContentPane(label);
    }

    public void run(){
        game.update();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){}
    }
}
```

Label:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Label extends JLabel{

    Game game;

    public Label(Game game){
       this.game = game;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics gfx){
        game.render(gfx);
    }
}
```

Game:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Game {

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float w = 20;
    float h = 20;

    void render(Graphics gfx){
        gfx.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);
    }

    void update(){
        x += 0.1f;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: A runnable JLabel doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Olivier I changed code to make JFrame runnable but still the same results. Rectangle is drawn but doesn't move. I updated code in  the question

Comment: *"run function from Runnable interface is automatically called"* That's wrong.

Comment: Please post an [mre] including a `main` method. For Swing animation use a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Usually, in _Swing_, when you want to do your own painting, you write a class that extends `javax.swing.JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method. Refer to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). If you want to add animation, you usually use a [Swing] timer. Refer to [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: I think you copied the `Label` class instead of the `Main` class. _Main:_ and _Label:_ are the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `main` method where you create a new `Thread` object, passing the Runnable class (i.e., `Frame` in your case) in that `Thread` instance, and subsequently `start` the `Thread`. See below:

```
public class Main
{     
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {    
        Game g = new Game();
        Label l = new Label(g);
        Frame f = new Frame(l, g);    
        Thread t1 =new Thread(f);   
        // this will call run() method in Frame class 
        t1.start();    
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:** Also, your Frame class should look like the one below. A Thread executes its run method once, and then it is considered completed. If you want to loop, you have to do it yourself (below a `while(true)` is used, which can be changed to some variable that you can turn to `false` when you want the program to exit). Finally, make sure to call `repaint()` after `game.update()` for the drawing to take effect.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    Game game;
    Label label;
    public Frame(Label label, Game game) {
        this.label = label;
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setTitle("idk");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setEnabled(true);
        this.game = game;
        this.setContentPane(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            game.update();
            label.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should be `sleep`ing on the EDT. Nor should you be updating the GUI on a thread which is not the EDT. Refer to [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)